# For which a does this sum(expected value) converge?

Tags: calculus, probability

How could I show that followinf series converges for $a < 1$:

$$ \sum_{x=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^a}{x(x+1)} $$

Question is basicaly for which a does this series converge.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry, the thing you wrote doesn't look like an infinite series! Could you please clarify?

Comment: Did you possibly mean an integral?  If so, over what range of $x$?

Comment: Edited, sorry! Im new to latex and completely forgot suation sign. Sorry :)

Comment: Post edit, your terms are $\frac {x^{a-1}}{x+1}<x^{a-2}$.  Does that help?

Comment: Notation:  it is very unusual for $x$ to denote a discrete index ($x$ tends to be used to denote a continuous variable).  To avoid possible confusion, I suggest changing $x$ to $n$ or $k$.

Comment: use summation by parts.